# Deleted ODBC Connection is still working

Tags: windows, iis, odbc

I am currently running IIS on a windows 7 workstation, and a while back I had set up different ODBC connections. I just removed them while trying to debug certain things, but my website is still working as though the connections were never deleted. When I go to my code, I still have the name of the connection in there, and when I change the name of the connection the webpage fails. However, when I put back the original name it continues to connect to the DB just fine.

I have tried restarting the IIS server, refreshing the App Pools, clearing my browser, and restarting my PC. I'm not sure if there is another place this ODBC connection could be getting stored, if it's not showing up in ODBC Administration.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized what I was doing wrong. Unfortunately I didn't realize there are both a 64-bit and a 32-bit version of the ODBC Data Source Manager. I had been opening the 32 bit version to try and delete the data sources, when in reality they were stored in the 64 bit version.